# How to display a Twitter feed with custom icon instead of profile image with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

So right now I am trying to style a twitter feed that will display on a website. I am using TweeCool to do this (http://www.tweecool.com/). Basically, I am trying to figure out how I can swap the profile thumbnail image, with a custom twitter icon. So basically what I want, is for each tweet to display back with a twitter font icon on the left side of it. With the code below I can get the first tweet displayed as I want but  it does not go through the JS loop to style the others. I am fairly new to JS and Jquery, so was wondering what I could do to make it so that each tweet would prepend the twitter icon to the left of the text such as the first one in the example. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
     <script src="http://api.tweecool.com/js/tweecool.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#tweecool').tweecool({
            //settings
             username : 'cnnbrk', 
             limit : 5,
             profile_image: false
          });
      });
    </script>

    <style>
        #tweecool ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .container-tweet {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
        }

        #tweecool {
            width: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 0px;
            line-height: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .tweetLogo {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 10px;
            width: 20%;
        }

        .tweetLogo i{
            color: blueviolet;
            font-size: 20px;

        }
      </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-tweet">
    <div class="tweetLogo"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
    <div id="tweecool"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? twitter logo with each tweet http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/tweet.html

Comment: hey @Shehary, yes this is what I was looking for! Thanks, can you post your solution?

Comment: Yeah i deleted the answer because its not according to the stackoverflow rules and can cost me the repute or down vote, anyways i added the link in above comment you can check and let know and i will post the code in answer

Comment: Hi, yes please post the answer to me so I know what you did.  Thank you!

Comment: did nothing fancy, just a small hack in tweecool plugin, give me couple of mins.

Comment: Answer posted, please check

Answer (score 0):

With default tweecool plugin its not possible so have to hack the plugin and put the icon inside `tweecool.js` so icon load with each tweet and just minor changes in css code as follow.

Set display none here if you don't want to show default icon

```
.tweetLogo i{
    display: none !important;

}
```

Add this in style so icon load with each tweet have color and fontsize

```
#tweecool i{
    color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;

}
```

remove this from `<head>`

```
<script src="http://api.tweecool.com/js/tweecool.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Create new `tweecool.js` blank file in root directory and add it in `<head>`

```
<script src="tweecool.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add following code in `tweecool.js` and you are good to go

```
/*Name : TweeCool
 *version: 1.6 
 *Description: Get the latest tweets from twitter.
 *Website: www.tweecool.com
 *Licence: No licence, feel free to do whatever you want.
 *Author: TweeCool
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({

        tweecool : function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                username : 'tweecool',
                limit : 5,
                profile_image : true,
                show_time : true,
                show_media : false,
                                show_media_size: 'thumb'  //values: small, large, thumb, medium 
            }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            function xTimeAgo(time) {
                var nd = new Date();
                //var gmtDate = Date.UTC(nd.getFullYear(), nd.getMonth(), nd.getDate(), nd.getHours(), nd.getMinutes(), nd.getMilliseconds());
                var gmtDate = Date.parse(nd);
                var tweetedTime = time * 1000; //convert seconds to milliseconds
                var timeDiff = (gmtDate - tweetedTime) / 1000; //convert milliseconds to seconds

                var second = 1, minute = 60, hour = 60 * 60, day = 60 * 60 * 24, week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, month = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

                if (timeDiff > second && timeDiff < minute) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / second) + " seconds ago";
                } else if (timeDiff >= minute && timeDiff < hour) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / minute) + " minutes ago";
                } else if (timeDiff >= hour && timeDiff < day) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / hour) + " hours ago";
                } else if (timeDiff >= day && timeDiff < week) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / day) + " days ago";
                } else if (timeDiff >= week && timeDiff < month) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / week) + " weeks ago";
                } else if (timeDiff >= month && timeDiff < year) {
                    return Math.round(timeDiff / month) + " months ago";
                } else {
                    return 'over a year ago';
                }

            }

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var wrapper = $(this);
                var wInner = $('<ul>').appendTo(wrapper);
                var urlpattern = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
                var usernamepattern = /@+(\w+)/ig;
                var hashpattern = /#+(\w+)/ig;
                                var media = '';

                $.getJSON("https://www.api.tweecool.com/?screenname=" + o.username + "&count=" + o.limit, function(data) {

                    if (data.errors || data == null) {
                        wrapper.html('No tweets available.');
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (o.profile_image) {
                        var pIMG = '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + o.username + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data.user.profile_image_url + '" alt="' + o.username + '" /></a>';
                    } else {
                        pIMG = '';
                    }

                    $.each(data.tweets, function(i, field) {

                        if (o.show_time) {
                            var timestamp = xTimeAgo(field.timestamp);
                        } else {
                            var timestamp = '';
                        }

                                                if(o.show_media && field.media_url){
                                                    media =  '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + o.username + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + field.media_url + ':'+o.show_media_size+'" alt="' + o.username + '" class="media" /></a>';
                                                }else{
                                                   media = ''; 
                                                }

                        wInner.append('<li> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>' + pIMG + '<div class="tweets_txt">' + field.text.replace(urlpattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>').replace(usernamepattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>').replace(hashpattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>') + media + ' <span>' + timestamp + '</span></div></li>');
                    });

                }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                    //var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
                    wrapper.html('No tweets available');
                });

            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

What I did is here, near the bottom of above `tweecool.js` i added the icon `<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>`

```
 wInner.append('<li> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>' + pIMG + '<div class="tweets_txt">' + field.text.replace(urlpattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>').replace(usernamepattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>').replace(hashpattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>') + media + ' <span>' + timestamp + '</span></div></li>');
                });
```

So it loads with each tweet

twitter logo with each tweet [Example](http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/tweet.html)